# removing \n and \r but not \r\n

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string with both `\r` and `\n` as well as `\r\n`.

How do we remove `\r` and `\n`, while keeping `\r\n` in tact?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Negative lookahead+lookbehind can do that:

```js
const test="a\nb\rc\r\nd\n\re";
console.log(test.replaceAll(/(\r(?!\n)|((?<!\r)\n))/g,"x"));
//                            ^^^^^^^^              match \r if it has no \n after
//                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^  match \n if it has no \r before
```

Only the `\r\n` between `c` and `d` are kept intact.